# Insert into data to database Error Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I want to insert my DataGridView datas to my database i used parametrs

these are my database fileds

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Order] (
    [Name]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Price]    INT          NULL,
    [Quantity] INT          NULL,
    [Total]    INT          NULL
);
```

and these are my codes

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-R34C6VV\\SQL;Initial Catalog=Student_Databse_2019_HW1;Integrated Security=True");

     con.Open();
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tbl_Order(Name, Price, Quantity, Total) values(@Name, @Price, @Qty, @Total",con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

I have an error on this code cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

it says 
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@Total'.**

I have 4 fields in my DataGridView
`Name , Price , Qty , Total`

any one know what is the problem?

Comment: Database is Quantity and c# is Qty.

Comment: It seems you're lacking the final parenthesis at the end of your SQL statement

Comment: @jdweng i change it to quantity too but still did not work

Comment: Have you tried using first SQL Server Profiler ?...look how the query come to your database

Comment: @OnkelToob i still do now know what is the problem i searched before i post but did not get anything

Comment: Are you looking down on the answers?

Comment: There are also some dubious and suboptimal things there.  A) Storing something like the total which is easily calculated is a bad idea, B) `Add(string, dbType).Value= ...` is to be preferred over  AddWithValue C) YOur DB Provider objects will gladly and easily updates your db for you without code fishing thru the DGV.  Good job on parameters though - nice to see

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp thanks for the suggestions i will try 
they found my problem thanks guys

Comment: You should use Parameters.Add instead of AddWithValue. It can do some really interesting things from time to time. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Also you should wrap your iDisposable objects (connections, commands etc) in the USING statement to make sure they are properly handled.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks i am gonna try that in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not closed the round bracket in your SQL statement.

Comment: :( i did not notice that 
well thanks too much for the help

Comment: Good spot @azhar-khorasany

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you're missing a ")" in your Insert statement.